# Upload Google Drive Files - PNG, JPEG, PDF

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I currently have a function that successfully uploads jpg files to google drive. I was wondering how to modify the function so that I can upload pdf, jpg, png, and docx files to google drive as well. Here is my code:

```
function uploadFiles($filePath) {
    $file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
    $file->setName(uniqid().'.jpg');
    $file->setDescription('A test document');
    $file->setMimeType('image/jpeg');

    $data = file_get_contents($filePath);

    $createdFile = $this->service->files->create($file, array(
        'data' => $data,
        'mimeType' => 'image/jpeg',
        'uploadType' => 'multipart'
    ));
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case that the files of `pdf, jpg, png, and docx` are uploaded as `pdf, jpg, png, and docx`, when a file is uploaded with the method of Files: create in Drive API, it seems that the mimeType of the file is automatically detected. I thought that in your case, this situation can be used. So please modify your script as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function uploadFiles($filePath) {
    $file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
    $file->setName(uniqid());
    $file->setDescription('A test document');

    $data = file_get_contents($filePath);

    $createdFile = $this->service->files->create($file, array(
        'data' => $data,
        'uploadType' => 'multipart'
    ));
}
```

- By above modification, for `pdf, jpg, png, and docx`, the uploaded file has the correct mimeType.